# Не получается установить tensorflow в Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

Мой Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9.13-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=index.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install setuptools==59.8.0 && pip install numpy==1.19.2
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
gensim==4.1.0
flask
razdel
pymorphy2
nltk==3.6.2
requests==2.27.1
tensorflow==2.6.0
```

Ошибка:

```
#0 8.879 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.6.0 (from versions: none)
#0 8.879 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.6.0
```

В файле requirements.txt я пробовал не указывать версию tensorflow, но у меня все равно такая же ошибка.

Comment: А если без указания версии, то ставится или так же нет? Да, и система 64-битная? А то в требованиях только такие вроде

Comment: @CrazyElf
 Без указания тоже была ошибка, как написано выше. Как проверить битность в docker?

Comment: А какой образ системы вы используете? В образе системы если есть `64`, то обычно `64`-битная система.

Comment: @CrazyElf
Не знаю, как понять какой образ системы использую?

Comment: Как я понял в Dockerfile у меня python:3.9.13-alpine3.16 - это какие-то образы, но образа системы я не вижу тут.

Comment: Скорее всего 64-битная будет называться `alpine3.16_x86_64`

Comment: @CrazyElf вот 64 битная: amd64/python:3.8-alpine3.16
Но даже с ней вылазит такая же ошибка

Comment: Ну тогда не знаю (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло исправить Dockerfile на:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9.13

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        cmake libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev protobuf-compiler \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=index.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0

RUN pip install setuptools==59.8.0 && pip install numpy==1.19.2
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```